# ERROR: Please sign or rebuild your APK using a production certificate or verify your keystore build settings are correct. - Oculus APK upload Error

Tags: android, certificate, apk, oculusquest

When I upload my APK to the Oculus developer hub it gives this error :
`ERROR: Please sign or rebuild your APK using a production certificate or verify your Keystore build settings are correct.` I couldn't figure out how to troubleshoot the problem. If anybody can help please do so, It would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Slash-Kill/PojavLauncher) if that helps.